# Check whether or not the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}-(2n-1)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to check whether or not the series converges.
the series is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}-(2n-1)$$
The first thing I thought of is to do multiply by his compliment and the result I get is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4n^2-4n+9-(2n-1)^2}{\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}+(2n-1)}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8}{\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}+(2n-1)}$$
the demand was to check it by the Comparison Test so I decide that this frac is:
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{8}{\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}+(2n-1)}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$and this function are not Convergent. 
the answer is Convergent.
what I did wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The series is not convergent. Everything is fine with your method except that you have to bound from below: $$\frac{8}{\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}+2n-1}>\frac{2}{n}.$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says it is not convergent... http://wolfr.am/17TOYD3

Comment: OK, the way I checked it right?

Comment: @O.L. how its bigger then $\frac{2}{n}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}+(2n-1)< \sqrt{4n^2}+2n$ for $n>2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\sqrt{4n^2-4n+9}-(2n-1)=\sqrt{(2n-1)^2+8}-(2n-1)=(2n-1)\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{8}{(2n-1)^2}}-1\right)\sim_\infty(2n-1)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{8}{(2n-1)^2}-1\right)=\frac{4}{(2n-1)}\sim_\infty\frac{2}{n}$$
so the given series is divergent.

Comment: I missed you on the third step.

Comment: @OfirAttia $(1+x)^{\alpha} \sim 1+\alpha x$ when $x\to 0$.