# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ converge?
I try to multiply this term by conjugate. Then I want to apply the comparison test

Comment: Yes, that would work.  It isn't clear where you got stuck.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/435484/9464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
\sqrt{n^2+1}-n=\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\ge \frac1{2n+1}.
$$

Comment: :-) Of course, I always love direct comparisons.

Comment: @Oliver Oloa thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\dfrac1{2n}}=1
$$

And then the p-series to see it diverges.

---

One may also readily use the binomial expansion formula to see that

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}=n+\frac1{2n}+\mathcal O(n^{-2})$$

which also shows divergence.